# Apply configuration yaml file via API or SDK

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl

I started a pod in kubernetes cluster which can call kubernetes api via go-sdk (like in this example: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration). I want to listen some external events in this pod (e.g. GitHub web-hooks), fetch `yaml` configuration files from repository and apply them to this cluster.

Is it possible to call `kubectl apply -f <config-file>` via kubernetes API (or better via golang SDK)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As yaml directly: no, not that I'm aware of. But if you increase the `kubectl` verbosity (`--v=100` or such), you'll see that the first thing `kubectl` does to your yaml file is convert it to json, and then `POST` *that* content to the API. So the spirit of the answer to your question is "yes."

This [box/kube-applier](https://github.com/box/kube-applier#readme) project may interest you. While it does not appear to be webhook aware, I am sure they would welcome a PR teaching it to do that. Using their existing project also means you benefit from all the bugs they have already squashed, as well as their nifty prometheus metrics integration.

Comment: Thanks, will use kube-applier, also submitted feature request for webhook support: https://github.com/box/kube-applier/issues/29